# i make a code to download a pdf but i do not know haw i can display it after download

Tags: android, kotlin

I am a new in kotlin and I make a code to download a pdf but i do not know haw i can display it after download so i need a code to display it. this the code to download:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var mydownloadid :Long = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val be1 = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.be)
        val be = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.be)
        be1.setOnClickListener {
            val Intent = Intent(this.baseContext,menu::class.java)
            startActivity(Intent)
        }

        be.setOnClickListener {
            var request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=13UzyQurtT29uKWDh8rW9IxHJ-Hu8vjKjqj80HhZF_pQ"))
                .setTitle("Download pdf")
                .setDescription("downloading pdf")
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)
                .setAllowedOverMetered(true)

            var dm =getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
            mydownloadid = dm.enqueue(request)

        }
var br = object:BroadcastReceiver(){
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        var id = p1?.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID,-1)
        if (id==mydownloadid)
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"تم انتهاء التحميل",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }

}

registerReceiver(br, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))




    }
}
```

Comment: Have s look at ACTION_VIEW.